# Find all possible sums of a blackjack hand consistes of 2 or more Aces

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, logic, blackjack

Let's say I have a hand of 3 Aces. In blackjack, each Ace can have a value of either 1 or 11. I need to find all possible summation of the Aces which are as follows:

```
1 , 1, 1 = 3
1 , 1, 11 = 13
1, 11, 1 = 13
1, 11, 11 = 23
11, 1, 1 = 13
11, 1, 11 = 23
11, 11, 1 = 23
11, 11, 11 = 33
```

The input of my example is a list of 3 Aces. where there is an API that evaluates each Ace and returns a list of two values (1,11) for each Ace. So the input becomes something like Z = ((1,11),(1,11),(1,11)). and the output should be all possible sum combinations of Z. note that the input number of Aces is unknown!

It is 2^(number of aces) number of combinations. Could you please guide me through the algorithm to find all possible values? thank you

Comment: @גלעדברקן the input is a list of Aces. Consider there is an API that evaluates the values of each card. In this case, where the card is an Ace it returns a list of 1 and 11 values. and the output is a list of all possible summations of the cards. Note that our input could be an unknown number of Aces. It could be 1, 2, 3, 4, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: you have a number `n` of aces in your hand, and want to list all the possible values of that hand.

The only decision you have to make to determine the value of your hand is: how many aces count as 11?

If we call `k` this number, then the number of aces counting as 1 is `n - k`.

This gives the following iterative algorithm:

```
list_of_possible_values = empty_list
for (k = 0; k <= n; k++)
{
    value = k * 11 + (n - k) * 1
    list_of_possible_values.push(value)
}
return list_of_possible_values
```

Note that you can simplify that further:

```
value = k * 11 + (n - k) * 1
value = k * (11 - 1) + n
value = k * 10 + n
```

This is an arithmetic progression. Increasing `k` by 1 results in increasing `value` by 10. We can rewrite the code accordingly:

```
list_of_possible_values = empty_list
for (v = n; v <= 11*n; v+=10)
{
    list_of_possible_values.push(v)
}
return list_of_possible_values
```

Most languages today have predefined functions to handle arithmetic progressions. In python:

```py
possible_values = range(n, 11*n+1, 10)
```